# Increasing Entropy on CoreOS

Tags: coreos, kubernetes, entropy-pool

I'm trying out coreos on a kubernetes cluster. This setup includes a bind server serving DNSSEC responses. Because of the DNSSEC key management, the bind server uses up all the available entropy and hangs on startup, and takes hours to get enough entropy to sign a single zone.

What can I do to increase the entropy on the servers to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Exactly what sort of "servers" are these?

Comment: These are virtual machines on GCE, which is why there are entropy problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should install [`haveged`](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/) in order to counter the lack of entropy sources in your specific setup.

If you have restricted access, try something like this:

https://github.com/harbur/docker-haveged

> In case you need an entropy gathering service on your docker host but
>   don't want to / can't install locally an entropy gathering service.
>
> The service makes more sense on Cloud servers and more specifically on
>   CoreOS servers where you cannot install locally services.

Comment: Although, please do note that this doesn't fix someone with restricted access (Assuming you mean from a privilege standpoint), as the container requires privileged mode to make the entropy available.